# Maven Integration-Test how to set-up POM correctly for different Profiles

Tags: java, integration-testing, maven-3, maven-plugin, maven-failsafe-plugin

I am having problems controlling how Maven copies resource files during the `Dev` Compile/Test steps and the `Integration-Test` Compile/Verify steps.

I've created two Profiles in Maven, `Dev` and `Integration-Test`. I've created a `config.properties` file for each profile. In my `src/test/resources` and `src/integration/resources` locations I have a `myappconfig.properties` file. I would like it so that the correct values from the respective profile `config.properties` are overlaid into these files and copied to the target/test-classes during the compile/test/verify steps for each profile (Dev/Integration-Test).

I am getting unwanted behaviour when running the `Dev` profile for the `Compile` and `Test` goals and unwanted behaviour for the `Integration-Test` profile during the `Compile` goal. I have summarised the expected and actual behaviour in the table below as its easier than writing it all out. I am also including the POM file listing and screenshots from my Intellij.

It seems like I need a way to stop the `build-helper-maven-plugin` from firing when the DEV profile is selected. Is there a way to set that up in the same way as I am able to skip the Integration Tests when running the DEV tests? or is the problem something else ?

Contents of config.property files

1) profiles/dev/config.properties

`server.message=hello_from_dev`

2) profiles/integration-test/config.properties

`server.message=hello_from_integration_test`

3) src/test/resources/myappconfig.properties

`## dev-test
config.${build.profile.id}server.message=${server.message}`

4) src/integration-test/resources/myappconfig.properties

`## integration-test
config.${build.profile.id}server.message=${server.message}`

Summary Table of Issues

[image]

POM Listing

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.stackoverflow</groupId>
  <artifactId>mavenintegrationtest</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>mavenintegrationtest</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <filters>
      <!--
                    Ensures that the config.properties file is always loaded from the
                    configuration directory of the active Maven profile.
    
                -->
      <filter>${basedir}/profiles/${build.profile.id}/config.properties</filter>
    </filters>

    <resources>
      <!--
                    Placeholders that are found from the files located in the configured resource
                    directories are replaced with the property values found from the profile
                    specific configuration file.
                -->
      <resource>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
      </resource>
    </resources>

    <testResources>
      <!--
                      <testResource>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                        <directory>src/integration-test/resources</directory>
                      </testResource>
                -->
      <testResource>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
        <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
      </testResource>
    </testResources>

    <pluginManagement>
      <!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
          <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
          <executions>
            <!-- Add executions here -->
            <!-- Add a new source directory to our build -->
            <execution>
              <id>add-integration-test-sources</id>
              <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>add-test-source</goal>
              </goals>
              <configuration>
                <!-- Configures the source directory of our integration tests -->
                <sources>
                  <source>src/integration-test/java</source>
                </sources>
              </configuration>
            </execution>
            <!-- Add a new resource directory to our build -->
            <execution>
              <id>add-integration-test-resources</id>
              <phase>generate-test-resources</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>add-test-resource</goal>
              </goals>
              <configuration>
                <!-- Configures the resource directory of our integration tests -->
                <resources>
                  <!--
                                            Placeholders that are found from the files located in the configured resource
                                            directories are replaced with the property values found from the profile
                                            specific configuration file.
                                        -->
                  <resource>
                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                    <directory>src/integration-test/resources</directory>
                  </resource>
                </resources>
              </configuration>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
          <configuration>
            <!-- Skips unit tests if the value of skip.unit.tests property is true -->
            <skipTests>${skip.unit.tests}</skipTests>
            <!-- Excludes integration tests when unit tests are run -->
            <excludes>
              <exclude>**/IT*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
          <executions>
            <!--
                                Invokes both the integration-test and the verify goals of the
                                Failsafe Maven plugin
                            -->
            <execution>
              <id>integration-tests</id>
              <goals>
                <goal>integration-test</goal>
                <goal>verify</goal>
              </goals>
              <configuration>
                <!--
                                        Skips integration tests if the value of skip.integration.tests
                                        property is true
                                    -->
                <skipTests>${skip.integration.tests}</skipTests>
              </configuration>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <!-- Profile configuration -->
  <profiles>
    <!-- The configuration of the development profile -->
    <profile>
      <id>dev</id>
      <!-- The development profile is active by default -->
      <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
      </activation>
      <properties>
        <!--
                        Specifies the build.profile.id property that must be equal than the name of
                        the directory that contains the profile specific configuration file.
                        Because the name of the directory that contains the configuration file of the
                        development profile is dev, we must set the value of the build.profile.id
                        property to dev.
                    -->
        <build.profile.id>dev</build.profile.id>
        <!--
                        Only unit tests are run when the development profile is active
                     -->
        <skip.integration.tests>true</skip.integration.tests>
        <skip.unit.tests>false</skip.unit.tests>
      </properties>
    </profile>
    <!-- The configuration of the integration-test profile -->
    <profile>
      <id>integration-test</id>
      <properties>
        <!--
                        Specifies the build.profile.id property that must be equal than the name of
                        the directory that contains the profile specific configuration file.
                        Because the name of the directory that contains the configuration file of the
                        production profile is prod, we must set the value of the build.profile.id
                        property to prod.
                    -->
        <build.profile.id>integration-test</build.profile.id>
        <!--
                        Only integration tests are run when the integration-test profile is active
                    -->
        <skip.integration.tests>false</skip.integration.tests>
        <skip.unit.tests>true</skip.unit.tests>
      </properties>
    </profile>
  </profiles>

</project>
```

Intellij Screenshots

[image]
[image]

Comment: you add a build section with the desired plugin configuration inside the profile section, that's the way you configure your build per profile. the build section outside of the profile you add the common configuration between both profiles

Comment: Take a look here: https://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/profiles-sect-maven-profiles.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had a go at changing my POM using the tip that @Jorge Campos gave me. I think it works ok. Please find below incase it can help someone.
Thank you for your advice @Jorge Campos - really the points should go to you but I cant give them for a comment.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.stackoverflow</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compilerpluginoverride</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <name>mavencompilerpluginoverride</name>
    <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
    <url>http://www.example.com</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>

        <filters>
            <!--
                Ensures that the config.properties file is always loaded from the
                configuration directory of the active Maven profile.
            -->
            <filter>profiles/${build.profile.id}/config.properties</filter>
        </filters>

        <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
            <plugins>
                <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.8.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0-M1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <!-- Skips unit tests if the value of skip.unit.tests property is true -->
                        <skipTests>${skip.unit.tests}</skipTests>
                        <!-- Excludes integration tests when unit tests are run -->
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>**/IT*.java</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.2</version>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.8.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.7.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>

        <plugins>

        </plugins>

    </build>

    <profiles>
        <!-- The Configuration of the development profile -->
        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <!--
                    Specifies the build.profile.id property that must be equal than the name of
                    the directory that contains the profile specific configuration file.
                    Because the name of the directory that contains the configuration file of the
                    development profile is dev, we must set the value of the build.profile.id
                    property to dev.
                -->
                <build.profile.id>dev</build.profile.id>
                <!--
                    Only unit tests are run when the development profile is active
                -->
                <skip.integration.tests>true</skip.integration.tests>
                <skip.unit.tests>false</skip.unit.tests>
            </properties>
            <build>
                <resources>
                    <!--
                        Placeholders that are found from the files located in the configured resource
                        directories are replaced with the property values found from the profile
                        specific configuration file.
                    -->
                    <resource>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
                <testResources>
                    <testResource>
                        <directory>src/test/java</directory>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </testResource>
                    <testResource>
                        <directory>src/integration-test/java</directory>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </testResource>
                    <testResource>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                        <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
                    </testResource>
                </testResources>
            </build>
        </profile>
        <!-- The Configuration of the integration-test profile -->
        <profile>
            <id>integration-test</id>
            <properties>
                <!--
                    Specifies the build.profile.id property that must be equal than the name of
                    the directory that contains the profile specific configuration file.
                    Because the name of the directory that contains the configuration file of the
                    integration-test profile is integration-test, we must set the value of the
                    build.profile.id property to integration-test.
                -->
                <build.profile.id>integration-test</build.profile.id>
                <!--
                    Only integration tests are run when the integration-test profile is active
                -->
                <skip.integration.tests>false</skip.integration.tests>
                <skip.unit.tests>true</skip.unit.tests>
            </properties>
            <build>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>src/test/</directory>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </resource>
                    <resource>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                        <directory>src/integration-test/resources</directory>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
                <testResources>
                </testResources>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                        <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.0.0</version>
                        <executions>
                            <!-- Add executions here -->
                            <!-- Add a new source directory to our build -->
                            <execution>
                                <id>add-integration-test-sources</id>
                                <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>add-test-source</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <!-- Configures the source directory of our integration tests -->
                                    <sources>
                                        <source>src/integration-test/java</source>
                                    </sources>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.0.0-M1</version>
                        <executions>
                            <!--
                                Invokes both the integration-test and the verify goals of the
                                Failsafe Maven plugin
                            -->
                            <execution>
                                <id>integration-tests</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>integration-test</goal>
                                    <goal>verify</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <!--
                                        Skips integration tests if the value of skip.integration.tests
                                        property is true
                                    -->
                                    <skipTests>${skip.integration.tests}</skipTests>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>

            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

</project>
```

[image: screenshot showing the Dev Profile being used]

[image: screenshot showing the Integration-Test Profile being used]